# I am using https://github.com/scaperot/the-BPM-detector-python/blob/master/bpm_detection/bpm_detection.py, how to input the audio file?

Tags: python, input

I'm using the following code to get the BPMS of a WAV file, but how do i input the audio file?

I tried to run

```
    bpm_detection.py --filename
```

but got IO error

The main function is as follows:

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process .wav file to 
    determine the Beats Per Minute.')
        parser.add_argument('--filename', required=True,
               help='.wav file for processing')
        parser.add_argument('--window', type=float, default=3,
               help='size of the the window (seconds) that will be scanned to determine the bpm.  Typically less than 10 seconds. [3]')

        args = parser.parse_args()
        samps,fs = read_wav(args.filename)
```

Comment: try ```python yourcode.py file.wav```

Comment: I got this error   File "bpm_detection.py", line 32
    except IOError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

use

```
python file.py --filename file.wav
```

or

```
python file.py --filename C:\path\path\test.wav
```

or

```
python file.py --filename C:\\path\\path\\test.wav
```

or

```
python file.py --filename ./test.wav
```

Comment: I got the same error `File "bpm_detection.py", line 32
    except IOError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: python 2 will be accessed using python only. or else you can check which version is being called by running just python in terminal.

Comment: Your error is comming from bpm_detection.py line 30. wf=wave.open(filename,'rb)    try running this line in python saperatrely